# Is the weighted shift strong frequently hypercyclic?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

**One sided Shift**

Let be $M$ separable metric space. Consider $X=M^{\mathbb{N}}$ the sequence space equipped with the product metric $d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i-y_i|/2^i$ . Define the shift map $\sigma:X\to X$ by putting in each sequence $x=(x_i)$, $\sigma(x)_i=x_{i+1}$. Then we have that the shift has the following propery: given $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$  there exists a uniform nonnegative integer $K$ such that for each $z\in X$ there exist $y\in \sigma^{-K}(z)\cap B(x,\epsilon)$.

**Weighted Shift**

Now $X=\ell^p({\mathbb{N}})$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$
endowed with it standard norm.
We fix values $0 < c < c'$ and  a sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ satisfying $\alpha_n \in (c, c')$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The  weighted shift associated to the sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$
is defined as the linear map $L : X \to X$ given by
$$
L((x_n)_{n \geqslant 1}) = (\alpha_n x_{n+1})_{n \geqslant 1} \,.
$$

For each $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define   $\beta_k^n \equiv  \alpha_k \ldots \alpha_{k+n-1}$,  if

\begin{eqnarray}
\label{dnn}
\sum_n (\beta_1^n)^{-p}<\infty
\end{eqnarray}
then is a known result that $L$ is **frequently hypercyclic** in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, which means that,there exists $x$ such that for any open set $V$ the set $N(x, V)=\{n: T^nx\in V\}$ has positive lower density, i.e
$$
\liminf_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\# N(x,V)\cap\{1,\ldots,n \}>0.
$$

**My Question:**

I'am looking for  to know if there exist any condition over the weight sequence $(\alpha_n)$ in order to have  a  property a a bit more stronger that frequently hypercyclicity for the  the weighted shift.

More precisely I would like to know any condition over the weight sequence $(\alpha_n)$ in order to have the following  property(silimar to the ordinary one-sided shift):  given $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$  a uniform nonnegative integer $K$ such that for each $z\in X$ there exists some  $y\in L^{-K}(z)\cap B(x,\epsilon)$.

Comment: This is not a variant of "aperiodicity", it is a variant of topological/metric transitivity. (I don't know a standard term for it, I would perhaps call it "uniform strong transitivity") Good question though.

Comment: I chose the term "aperiodic" motivated by the theory of discrete Markov processes (finite state space). In this context if the adjacency matrix A is aperiodic (i.e. there exists n such that A^n>0) then the subshift the mentioned property  in the post above. Also the associated markov chain is called aperiodic. Maybe is not the most appropriate, but like you mention I also don't know a standard term for it.

Comment: @VilleSalo I have made some minor edits on the question. Consulting the literature of linear operators I found that the property that I am looking for is closer to the property called "frequently hypercyclic".

Comment: You are right about aperiodic matrices, indeed the term is not as crazy as I thought. (For matrices a lot of usually different dynamical notions coincide.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question is no. If the sequence $\alpha = (\alpha_{n})_{\geqslant 1}$ satisfies the condition $c<\alpha_{n}<c^\prime$ there is no other condition on a sequence $\alpha$ for the answer to be affirmative.  Let's assume that the answer to the question is affirmative. That is, there exists $\alpha = (\alpha_{n})_{n\geqslant 1}\in [c,c^{\prime}]^{\mathbb{N}-{0}}$ such that for every open ball $B(x,\epsilon)\subset \ell^p({\mathbb{N}})$ there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $z\in \ell^p({\mathbb{N}})$ there exists $y=(y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} = (y_0,y_1,y_3,\ldots,y_n,\ldots)$ satisfying the condition
$$
{\rm (i)}\; y\in\ell^{p}(\mathbb{N}),
\qquad 
{\rm (ii)}\;y\in L^{-K}_{\alpha}(z) 
\qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad 
{\rm (iii)}\; y\in B(x,\epsilon)
$$
We observe that for every integer $K\geqslant 1$ and every $({\bf u}_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ we have, in a susceptible way,
$$
L^{K}_{\alpha}\Big( ({\bf u}_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}  \Big) = \left( \Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}\Big)\cdot {\bf u}_{K+n} \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.
$$
From the observation we made above about the $L_{\alpha}$ operator the first condition below is an immediate consequence of the assumption we made.  Furthermore, the second condition is a consequence of the first condition and the third condition is a consequence of the second condition.

**Condition 1.** there exists $\alpha = (\alpha_{n})_{n\geqslant 1}\in [c,c^{\prime}]^{\mathbb{N}-{0}}$ such that for any open ball $B(x, \epsilon)\subset \ell^p({ \mathbb{N}})$ there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $z=(z_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ there exists $ y=(y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfying
$$
{\rm (i)}\; \|y\|_{p}<\infty,
\qquad 
{\rm (ii)}\;\Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}\Big)\cdot y_{K+n}=z_{n} \quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\quad \mbox { and } \quad 
{\rm (iii)}\;\| y-x\|_p<\epsilon 
$$
**Condition 2.** there exists $\alpha = (\alpha_{n})_{n\geqslant 1}\in [c,c^{\prime}]^{\mathbb{N}-{0}}$ such that for any open ball $B(x, \epsilon)\subset \ell^p( {\mathbb{N}})$ there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $z=(z_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ there exists $ y=(y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfying
$$
{\rm (i)}\; \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|z_n|^{p}<\infty,
\qquad 
{\rm (ii)}\; y_{K+n}= \Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}^{-1}\Big)\cdot z_{n}\quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\quad \mbox { and } \quad 
{\rm (iii)}\;\sum_{n=0}^{K-1}\left|y_{n} - x_n\right|^{p}
+
\sum_{n=K}^{\infty}\left|\Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}^{-1}\Big)\cdot z_{n} - x_n\right|^{p} <\epsilon 
$$
**Condition 3.** there exists $\alpha = (\alpha_{n})_{n\geqslant 1}\in [c,c^{\prime}]^{\mathbb{N}-\{0\}}$
such that for any open ball $B(x, \epsilon)\subset \ell^p( \mathbb{N})$
there exists a $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every pair $z=(z_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$
and $\tilde{z}=(\tilde{z}_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$
there exists $ y=(y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ which fits both $z$ and $\tilde{z}$ satisfying

$$
{\rm (i)}\; \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|z_n|^{p}<\infty,
\qquad 
{\rm (ii)}\; y_{K+n}= \Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}^{-1}\Big)\cdot z_{n}\quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\quad \mbox { and } \quad 
{\rm (iii)}\sum_{n=0}^{K-1}\left|y_{n} - x_n\right|^{p}
+
\sum_{n=K}^{\infty}\left|\Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}^{-1}\Big)\cdot z_{n} - x_n\right|^{p} <\epsilon 
$$
$$
{\rm (iv)}\; \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\tilde{z}_n|^{p}<\infty,
\qquad 
{\rm (v)}\; y_{K+n}= \Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}^{-1}\Big)\cdot \tilde{z}_{n}\quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\quad \mbox { and } \quad 
{\rm (vi)}\; \sum_{n=0}^{K-1}\left|y_{n} - x_n\right|^{p}
+
\sum_{n=K}^{\infty}\left|\Big( \prod_{\ell=1}^{K}\alpha_{\ell+n}^{-1}\Big)\cdot \tilde{z}_{n} - x_n\right|^{p} <\epsilon 
$$

Since $z=(z_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\tilde{z}=(\tilde{z}_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are arbitrary we can choose their $K$ first coordinates equal and the others different such that $\|\tilde{z}-z \|_p\geqslant 3\epsilon $. Adding member by member the equalities {\rm (ii)} and {\rm (v)} will result in $z=(z_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}=\tilde{z}=(\tilde{z}_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ since $0<c<\alpha_{n}$. However, this is a contradiction.

Comment: I'am very glad for you interest in the question I had ask. But I figure out a answer embarrassingly simple. For every $N$, any continuous linear operator dilates(or contracts) a ball of finite radius  for a factor of at most $\|T\|^n$.